# Why do my circle nodes not draw correctly in the d3 force directed graph?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3-force-directed

I am not sure why my circle nodes are not drawing in this case. My goal is to have fine-tuned control over the element being created for each node based on the node data (d). I do not always want circles.

Looking at what this code generates, I see:

[image: generated html]

circle are being added to the svg with a radius and fill color. However, they are not drawn.

But, if I do:

```
    const node = svg
      .append('g')
      .attr('stroke', '#fff')
      .attr('stroke-width', 1.5)
      .selectAll()
      .data(nodes)
      .join((enter) => enter.append('circle'))
      .attr('r', 16)
      .attr('fill', (d) => color(d.group))
```

I see:

[image]

The svg code is identical. I do see that there is a `circle[Attributes Style]` applied to each circle element. But, I am not sure why that is there in the second case, but not the first.

How can I use a function to create different node elements based on the node data? How does my code need to change so the circles will be drawn while still using a function passed to `enter.append` so I can return an arbitrary element?

```js
    const width = 1000
    const height = 400

    const node_data = Array.from({ length: 5 }, () => ({
      group: Math.floor(Math.random() * 3),
    }))

    const edge_data = Array.from({ length: 10 }, () => ({
      source: Math.floor(Math.random() * 5),
      target: Math.floor(Math.random() * 5),
      value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1,
    }))

    const links = edge_data.map((d) => ({ ...d }))
    const nodes = node_data.map((d, index) => ({ id: index, ...d }))
    
    const color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10)

    const svg = d3.select('#chart')

    const simulation = d3
      .forceSimulation(nodes)
      .force(
        'link',
        d3
          .forceLink(links)
          .id((d) => d.id)
          .distance((d) => 100)
      )
      .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody())
      .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
      .on('tick', ticked)

    const link = svg
      .append('g')
      .attr('stroke', '#999')
      .attr('stroke-opacity', 0.6)
      .selectAll()
      .data(links)
      .join('line')
      .attr('stroke-width', (d) => Math.sqrt(d.value))

    const node = svg
      .append('g')
      .attr('stroke', '#fff')
      .attr('stroke-width', 1.5)
      .selectAll()
      .data(nodes)
      .join((enter) =>
        enter.append((d) => {
          return document.createElement('circle')
        })
      )
      .attr('r', 16)
      .attr('fill', (d) => color(d.group))      

    node.append('title').text((d) => `hello ${d.id}`)

    function ticked() {
      link
        .attr('x1', (d) => d.source.x)
        .attr('y1', (d) => d.source.y)
        .attr('x2', (d) => d.target.x)
        .attr('y2', (d) => d.target.y)

      node.attr('cx', (d) => d.x).attr('cy', (d) => d.y)
    }
```

```css
    .graph {
      width: 1000px;
      height: 400px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<svg ref="chart" id="chart" class="graph"></svg>
```

Comment: The SVG code may look identical, but if you check `element.namespaceURI` you can see that the `<circle>`s are not interpreted the same way. To create an SVG circle element, you can't use `document.createElement('circle')`. It should be `document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle')` instead

Comment: With all due respect to my fellow contributors, I have solved the problem approximately 5 minutes before them. You can verify this by hovering over the time in the tooltip. Now, it's up to you to decide whether to support my contribution.  @Eric G

Comment: @AkashRam I would ask that you make your answer complete by including what qrsngky wrote. I would like the burden of future seekers to be reduced by not forcing them to not only read your excellent answer, but scattered comments as well for the full context. Once you do that, I will mark your correct answer as correct.

Comment: To find the namespace URI of an element in JavaScript, you can access the namespaceURI property of the element. Here's a simple example:                             ```var element = document.getElementById("yourElementId");
var namespaceURI = element.namespaceURI;
console.log(namespaceURI); ``` @Eric G

Answer (score 0):

kindly update the code
`.join(enter => { const elementType = d => document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle'); return enter.append(elementType); })`

```js
    const width = 1000
    const height = 400

    const node_data = Array.from({ length: 5 }, () => ({
      group: Math.floor(Math.random() * 3),
    }))

    const edge_data = Array.from({ length: 10 }, () => ({
      source: Math.floor(Math.random() * 5),
      target: Math.floor(Math.random() * 5),
      value: Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1,
    }))

    const links = edge_data.map((d) => ({ ...d }))
    const nodes = node_data.map((d, index) => ({ id: index, ...d }))
    
    const color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10)

    const svg = d3.select('#chart')

    const simulation = d3
      .forceSimulation(nodes)
      .force(
        'link',
        d3
          .forceLink(links)
          .id((d) => d.id)
          .distance((d) => 100)
      )
      .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody())
      .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
      .on('tick', ticked)

    const link = svg
      .append('g')
      .attr('stroke', '#999')
      .attr('stroke-opacity', 0.6)
      .selectAll()
      .data(links)
      .join('line')
      .attr('stroke-width', (d) => Math.sqrt(d.value))

    const node = svg
      .append('g')
      .attr('stroke', '#fff')
      .attr('stroke-width', 1.5)
      .selectAll()
      .data(nodes)
       .join(enter => {
    const elementType = d => document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'circle');
    return enter.append(elementType);
  })
      .attr('r', 16)
      .attr('fill', (d) => color(d.group))      

    node.append('title').text((d) => `hello ${d.id}`)

    function ticked() {
      link
        .attr('x1', (d) => d.source.x)
        .attr('y1', (d) => d.source.y)
        .attr('x2', (d) => d.target.x)
        .attr('y2', (d) => d.target.y)

      node.attr('cx', (d) => d.x).attr('cy', (d) => d.y)
    }
```

```css
.graph {
      width: 1000px;
      height: 400px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<svg ref="chart" id="chart" class="graph"></svg>
```

Comment: You're attempting to directly append a function (d) => {...} to the selection. This isn't how D3's join and append methods typically work together. The append method expects a string representing the element name or a function that returns a DOM element. Here, you're passing a function that returns a DOM element directly. @Eric G

Comment: If you could incorporate your comment into the answer and the comment above made by @qrsngky, I will mark this answer as correct. If you could also include how to check what the element.namespaceURI is for an element, that would be helpful as well.